# PowerPoint VBA: "No currently active document window" upon closing the file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The script takes photos from the indicated folder and places them on slides according to the limit imposed by the user, e.g. 1000 photos / presentation. After that it has to create a new presentation.

It was working. But he stopped. Now I stop with a PowerPoint VBA error: "No currently active document window" at the moment when the script is to close the PowerPoint file and open a new one in which to continue saving the presentation.

```
Saving and closing a newly created presentation
         Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsNone
         ActivePresentation.Save
         ActiveWindow.Close <----- error here
         Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsAll
```

How to eliminate this error for the script to continue running?

All Code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Option Private Module

Private il_plik As Integer
Private dostep_do_zdjec As Variant
Private tablica() As Variant

'Dla odwiedzających forum elektroda.pl - jeśli im się na coś przyda :)


Sub a_Dodaj_zdjecia_do_ppt()
Dim ogranicznik As Integer, roz_cznk_prw_str As Integer, roz_cznk_przezr As Integer
Dim plik As Integer, indeks As Integer, prezent As Integer, maks_zdj_prez As Integer
Dim maks_prez As Double
Dim cznk_prw_str As String, cznk_przezr As String, filterek As String, dostep_do_prez As String
Dim nazwa_prezent As String, nazwa_zdj As String, opis_zdj As String, prw_str As String
Dim opis_nagl_calej_prez As String, data_zdj As String, godzina_zdj As String
Dim info01 As String, info02 As String, info03 As String, info04 As String, info05 As String, info06 As String
Dim stempel_daty As Date
Dim il_zdj_w_prez As Variant
Dim nPrzezPrez As Object

'On Error GoTo koniec_blad
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Ograniczenie maksymalnej ilości zdjęć na jedną prezentację
    ogranicznik = 3000
    
    'Ustawienia czcionki strony przewodniej - można sobie zmieniać poprzez tę zmienną
    cznk_prw_str = "Arial" 'oryginalnie było "Calibri" - jednak ta czcionka z polskimi ą, ę, itd. nie wyświetlała się u mnie najlepiej
    roz_cznk_prw_str = 36 '40
    
    'Ustawienia czcionki strony przezrocza - można sobie zmieniać poprzez tę zmienną
    cznk_przezr = "Arial" 'oryginalnie było "Calibri" - jednak ta czcionka z polskimi ą, ę, itd. nie wyświetlała się u mnie najlepiej
    roz_cznk_przezr = 16 '18
    '
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '
    'Określenie opisu w nagłówku pojedynczej prezentacji - domyślne dla całej prezentacji
    opis_nagl_calej_prez = Trim(InputBox("Proszę podać treść nagłówka dla przezroczy w prezentacji", "Treść nagłówka w prezentacji", "Zdjęcie wykonane w Kluczborku"))
    
    'Określenie ilości zdjęć w pojedynczej prezentacji - domyślnie 500 szt.
    il_zdj_w_prez = InputBox("Proszę podać ilość zdjęć na 1 prezentację", "Ilość zdjęć do umieszczenia w prezentacji", 500)
    
    'Jeśli podano złą wartość
    If il_zdj_w_prez = "" Or Not IsNumeric(Trim(il_zdj_w_prez)) Then
        MsgBox "Podano złą wartość lub w ogóle jej nie podano" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Koniec procedury", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Uwaga !"
        GoTo koniec
    End If
    
    'Jeśli podano dobrą wartość, ale w 'granicach przyzwoitości' typu Integer dla zmiennej 'ogranicznik'
    il_zdj_w_prez = Abs(CInt(Trim(il_zdj_w_prez)))
    If il_zdj_w_prez > ogranicznik Then
        MsgBox "Przekroczono wartość graniczną" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Koniec procedury", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Uwaga !"
        GoTo koniec
    End If
    
    'Określenie dostępu do katalogu ze zdjęciami
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        filterek = ActivePresentation.Path
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Wybierz"
        .InitialFileName = filterek
        .Title = "Proszę wybrać katalog ze zdjęciami"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            dostep_do_zdjec = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "Nie podano dostępu do katalogu zdjęć" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Koniec procedury", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Uwaga !"
            GoTo koniec
        End If
    End With
    
    'Określenie dostępu do katalogu zapisywanych prezentacji
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        filterek = ActivePresentation.Path
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Wybierz"
        .InitialFileName = filterek
        .Title = "Proszę podać miejsce zapisu prezentacji"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            dostep_do_prez = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "Nie podano dostępu do katalogu prezentacji" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Koniec procedury", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Uwaga !"
            GoTo koniec
        End If
    End With
    
    'Początek obróbki
    MsgBox "Teraz rozpocznie się pobieranie nazw zdjęć" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Może to trochę potrwać, zależnie od ich ilości", vbOKOnly, "Uwaga !"
    
    'Pozyskanie nazw plików oraz ich posortowanie, wzrastająco, według daty utworzenia
    'Pobrane zostaną tylko zdjęcia z rozszerzeniami: '*.bmp', '*.gif', '*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png'
    Call b_Lista_plikow_w_katalogu(dostep_do_zdjec)
    Call c_sortowanie_babelkowe(tablica)
    
    'Korekta liczby zdjęć w prezentacji, jeśli zadeklarowano większą ich ilość niż liczba wszystkich zdjęć do obróbki
    If il_zdj_w_prez > il_plik Then il_zdj_w_prez = il_plik
    
    'Określenie ilości prezentacji, jaka zostanie utworzona,
    'w oparciu o ogólną ilość zdjęć i tych, przypadających na pojedynczą prezentację
    maks_prez = (il_plik / il_zdj_w_prez) - Fix(il_plik / il_zdj_w_prez)
    If maks_prez > 0 And maks_prez < 0.5 Then
        maks_prez = Round(il_plik / il_zdj_w_prez, 0) + 1
    Else
        maks_prez = Round(il_plik / il_zdj_w_prez, 0)
    End If
    
    'Wartości początkowe zmiennych wyznaczających zakres 'od-do' zdjęć w prezentacji
    maks_zdj_prez = il_zdj_w_prez
    plik = 1
    
    For prezent = 1 To maks_prez
        'Utworzenie nazwy nowopowstającej prezentacji
        Select Case prezent
            Case Is <= 9: nazwa_prezent = "Prez_" & "000" & prezent & ".ppt"
            Case Is <= 99: nazwa_prezent = "Prez_" & "00" & prezent & ".ppt"
            Case Is <= 999: nazwa_prezent = "Prez_" & "0" & prezent & ".ppt"
            Case Else: nazwa_prezent = "Prez_" & "" & prezent & ".ppt"
        End Select
        
        'Utworzenie i zapisanie na dysku nowopowstającej prezentacji - okno prezentacji widoczne - 'msoTrue'
        Presentations.Add(WithWindow:=msoTrue).SaveAs dostep_do_prez & "\" & nazwa_prezent
        
        'Zmiana wielkości okna programu
        'ActiveWindow.View.Zoom = 75
        
        'Wartość początkowa zmiennej ustalającej położenie danego przezrocza w prezentacji
        indeks = 0
        
        For plik = plik To maks_zdj_prez
            'Wydzielenie nazwy kopiowanego zdjęcia oraz daty i godziny jego utworzenia
            nazwa_zdj = Mid(tablica(plik), InStr(1, tablica(plik), ";", 1) + 1, Len(tablica(plik)) - InStr(1, tablica(plik), ";", 1))
            stempel_daty = CDate(Mid(tablica(plik), 1, InStr(1, tablica(plik), ";", 1) - 1))
            data_zdj = Format(stempel_daty, "dd.mm.yyyy")
            godzina_zdj = Format(stempel_daty, "hh:mm")
            
            'Zmienna na ewentualny, dodatkowy opis w nagłówku przezrocza pobrany z tablicy - tu niewykorzystana
            opis_zdj = "Opis dodatkowy"
            
            'Dodanie nowego przezrocza
            indeks = indeks + 1
            ActivePresentation.Slides.Add Index:=indeks, Layout:=ppLayoutBlank
            
            'Przypisanie obiektu przezrocza do zmiennej - skrócenie zapisu obiektu
            Set nPrzezPrez = ActivePresentation.Slides(indeks)
            
            'Wkopiowanie zdjęcia
            'LinkToFile:=msoFalse - teoretycznie uniezależnia wkopiowane zdjęcie od 'zdjęcia macierzystego' pobranego z katalogu
            nPrzezPrez.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=dostep_do_zdjec & "\" & nazwa_zdj, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=28, Top:=40, Width:=665, Height:=460
            
            'Skalowanie wkopiowanego zdjęcia - zmianą liczby przy 'ScaleHeight' i 'ScaleWidth'
            With nPrzezPrez.Shapes(1)
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                '.ScaleHeight 1.4, msoTrue, msoScaleFromMiddle 'msoScaleFromTopLeft 'msoScaleFromMiddle 'msoScaleFromBottomRight
                '.ScaleWidth 1.4, msoTrue, msoScaleFromMiddle
                .Width = 665
                .Height = 460
            End With
            
            'Dodanie nagłówka
            nPrzezPrez.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeWave, 8.5, 9#, 703#, 62.38).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Zdjęcie nr " & Format(plik, "#,##0") & ": " & opis_nagl_calej_prez
            'nPrzezPrez.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeWave, 8.5, 9#, 703#, 62.38).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Zdjęcie nr " & Format(plik, "#,##0") & " (" & nazwa_zdj & ")"
            'Inny układ opisu nagłówka - "Zdjęcie nr " & Format(plik, "#,##0") & ": " & nazwa_zdj & " - " & opis_zdj
            
            'Formatowanie nagłówka
            With nPrzezPrez.Shapes(2)
                With .TextFrame
                    .AutoSize = ppAutoSizeNone
                    .WordWrap = msoFalse
                    With .TextRange
                        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
                        With .Font
                            .Name = cznk_przezr: .Size = roz_cznk_przezr: .Bold = msoTrue
                            .Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                            '.Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
                With .Fill
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(215, 228, 189)
                    .Solid
                    .Transparency = 0#
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                End With
                With .Line
                    .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(79, 98, 40)
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                End With
            End With
            
            'Dodanie stopki
            nPrzezPrez.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeWave, 8.5, 472#, 703#, 62.38).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "DATA: " & data_zdj & ", godzina " & godzina_zdj
            
            'Formatowanie stopki
            With nPrzezPrez.Shapes(3)
                With .TextFrame
                    .AutoSize = ppAutoSizeNone
                    .WordWrap = msoFalse
                    With .TextRange
                        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
                        With .Font
                            .Name = cznk_przezr: .Size = roz_cznk_przezr: .Bold = msoTrue
                            .Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                            '.Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
                With .Fill
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(215, 228, 189)
                    .Solid
                    .Transparency = 0#
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                End With
                With .Line
                    .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(79, 98, 40)
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                End With
            End With
            
            'Usunięcie dotychczasowych przypisań do zmiennych
            Set nPrzezPrez = Nothing
            
            nazwa_zdj = ""
            stempel_daty = #1/1/1980#
            data_zdj = ""
            godzina_zdj = ""
            opis_zdj = ""
            
            'Co każde 1000 zdjęć 'odpuść' odrobinę na inne czynności - 'Niepraktyczne' w tym zadaniu
            'If plik Mod 1000 = 0 Then DoEvents
        Next plik
        
        'Zmienna z tytułem prezentacji do strony przewodniej
        prw_str = "PREZENTACJE" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "TYTUŁ" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "ILOŚĆ ZDJĘĆ: " & Format(indeks, "#,##0") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "OSTATNIA AKTUALIZACJA:" & vbCrLf & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy")
        
        'Wstawienie strony przewodniej
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Add Index:=1, Layout:=ppLayoutTitleOnly
        
        'Sformatowanie strony przewodniej
        With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
            .Left = 54#
            .Top = 167.75
            .Width = 612.12
            .Height = 115.62
            With .TextFrame
                .AutoSize = ppAutoSizeNone
                .WordWrap = msoTrue
                With .TextRange
                    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
                    .Text = prw_str
                    With .Font
                        .Name = cznk_prw_str: .Size = roz_cznk_prw_str
                        .Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                        '.Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
                    End With
                End With
            End With
            With .Fill
                .Solid
                .Transparency = 0#
                .Visible = msoFalse
            End With
            With .Line
                .Visible = msoFalse
            End With
        End With
        
        'Zapis i zamknięcie nowoutworzonej prezentacji
        Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsNone
        ActivePresentation.Save
       ' ActiveWindow.Close
       ActivePresentation.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsAll
        
        'Czyszczenie zmiennej z tytułem prezentacji do strony przewodniej - na wszelki wypadek
        prw_str = ""
        
        'Jeśli przekroczono dopuszczalne wartości zmiennych, określone na początku, to korekta
        'Można tu zastosować zmienną 'indeks'
        maks_zdj_prez = il_zdj_w_prez + plik - 1
        If maks_zdj_prez > il_plik Then maks_zdj_prez = il_plik
    Next prezent
    
    'Komunikat końcowy
    info01 = "Procedura zakończona" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    info02 = "Utworzono " & Format(maks_prez, "#,##0") & " prezentacje(-ę/-i) w: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    info03 = dostep_do_prez & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    info04 = "z " & Format(il_plik, "#,##0") & " zdjęć, po maksimum " & Format(il_zdj_w_prez, "#,##0") & " w każdej," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    info05 = "pobranych z:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    info06 = dostep_do_zdjec
    
    MsgBox info01 & info02 & info03 & info04 & info05 & info06, vbOKOnly, "Uwaga !"
Exit Sub
    
    'Wykonaj jeśli w trakcie obróbki pojawił się jakiś błąd
koniec_blad:
    On Error GoTo 0: On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsNone
    With Presentations(nazwa_prezent)
        .Saved = True: .Close
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsAll
    Set nPrzezPrez = Nothing
    
    'Wykonaj po błędzie wyboru katalogu lub odwołaniu operacji ustalającej ilość zdjęć w prezentacji
koniec:
    End
End Sub

Sub b_Lista_plikow_w_katalogu(dostep_do_zdjec As Variant)
Dim igt As Integer
Dim dlg As Integer, poz As Integer, licz As Integer
Dim rozsz_pliku As String
Dim ciag_prw As String, ciag_odtw As String, znak As String
Dim plik As Variant
Dim apli As Object, katalog As Object

On Error GoTo koniec
    Set apli = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set katalog = apli.Namespace(dostep_do_zdjec)
    
    'Inicjalizacja tablicy przechowującej dane o plikach zdjęć
    ReDim tablica(1)
    igt = 0
    
    'Wpisanie informacji o plikach do tablicy
    For Each plik In katalog.Items
        'Wykonaj jeśli ma rozszerzenie
        If InStrRev(plik, ".", -1, 1) <> 0 Then
            rozsz_pliku = LCase(Mid(plik, InStrRev(plik, ".", -1, 1), 5))
            
            'Pobierane będą dane tylko niektórych plików
            If rozsz_pliku = ".jpg" Or rozsz_pliku = ".jpeg" Then
                ciag_prw = CStr(katalog.GetDetailsOf(plik, 12))
                
                'Dziwna wartość po wykonaniu <<katalog.GetDetailsOf(plik, 12)>>, tj. "?01-?03-?2017 ??19:21"
                'Poniżej odtworzenie zapisu daty
                dlg = Len(ciag_prw)
                poz = 0
                For licz = 1 To dlg
                    poz = poz + 1
                    znak = Mid(ciag_prw, poz, 1)
                    If Asc(znak) <> 63 Then ciag_odtw = ciag_odtw & znak
                Next licz
                If ciag_odtw = "" Then ciag_odtw = "01-01-1980 00:00"
                
                igt = igt + 1
                ReDim Preserve tablica(igt)
                tablica(igt) = ciag_odtw & ";" & katalog.GetDetailsOf(plik, 0)
                ciag_odtw = ""
            Else
                ciag_prw = CStr(katalog.GetDetailsOf(plik, 3))
                If ciag_prw = "" Then ciag_prw = "01-01-1980 00:00"
                
                igt = igt + 1
                ReDim Preserve tablica(igt)
                tablica(igt) = ciag_prw & ";" & katalog.GetDetailsOf(plik, 0)
                ciag_prw = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next plik
    
    'Wstawia do zmiennej modułowej informację o ilości plików w tablicy
    il_plik = igt
    
    Set apli = Nothing
    Set katalog = Nothing
    
Exit Sub
koniec:
    Set apli = Nothing
    Set katalog = Nothing
End Sub

Sub c_sortowanie_babelkowe(tablica As Variant)
Dim pocz As Integer, koniec As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim przech As Variant

On Error GoTo koniec
    pocz = LBound(tablica)
    koniec = UBound(tablica)
    
    For i = pocz To koniec - 1
        For j = i + 1 To koniec
            If tablica(i) > tablica(j) Then
                przech = tablica(j)
                tablica(j) = tablica(i)
                tablica(i) = przech
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
Exit Sub
koniec:
End Sub
```

Edit://

I found a temporary solution to this. I fired this code, without the patch you wrote about on another computer, where I literally closed all windows in the window. Only the powerpoint was opened. The window with the script was on top. I didn't touch anything and the script worked fine on a large batch of photos (> 10k), creating a total of 11 presentation files. Can you explain to me as someone who is into programming and certainly VB programming does not know why this is happening and how to "remove" this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save & Close powerpoint through Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511853/save-close-powerpoint-through-excel-vba)

Comment: @braX: I don't see a solution here

Comment: You want `ActivePresentation.Close`, not `ActiveWindow.Close`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.close

Comment: @braX I modified the thread by adding the whole script, maybe this will help to locate the problem?

I can somehow send a ready powerpoint file + a sample package of photos for self-run

Comment: You know what I did? I fired this code, without the patch you wrote about on another computer, where I literally closed all windows in the window. Only the powerpoint was opened. The window with the script was on top. I didn't touch anything and the script worked fine on a large batch of photos (> 10k), creating a total of 11 presentation files. Can you explain to me as someone who is into programming and certainly VB programming does not know why this is happening and how to "remove" this problem?